# screen orientation - reverse portrait

Tags: android, orientation, reverse, portrait

I have a very basic layout with a `Frame` and a `TextView`.
When I put my phone upside down (reverse portrait) the Text is not facing me, the screen does not rotate. Is it en intended behavior that by default the screen only rotate in 3 direction?

```
<TextView
    android:text="Text"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="70dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
```

Manifest:

```
<activity
        android:name=".Menu"
        android:screenOrientation="user"/>
```

From what I could gather through researches it is part of the default settings of recent android OSs. Would I need to program anything complex to get this working? Or a small setting would do the job (like adding a layout)?

I target OS 5+ (*API 21*)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `AndroidManifest.xml` file, you need to configure the `<activity>` to use the orientation from the sensor. This should be the default, but you can force it to the sensor's orientations, for all 4 possible orientations, with `android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"`

```
<activity
            android:name=".ui.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
```